# Why parsing error unexpected token < appearing in the following line of code in PHP Javascript when it is as per example tutorial?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get a value assigning in Javascript variable directly using PHP-JSON as following

```
var productVatValue = <?php echo json_encode($productVatValue) ?>;
```

I have also tried solution

```
var productVatValue = <?php echo json_encode($productVatValue, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
```

from the post here
[How do I pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript) but same error " parsing error unexpected token < " is showing on the line -- how I can solve the error?

Comment: What exactly is the error message and which file and line of code does it refer to? Is your PHP actually running / being parsed for this file? If you view the page source (as in right-click -> _"View page source"_), what does it look like?

Comment: @Phil,
Yes, I can get the data from PHP and here is the error: 
 " parsing error unexpected token < "

page here is the code on php
{
[code]
<?php  

require_once 'core.php';

//$productVat = $_POST['productVat'];

$sqlvat = "SELECT vat FROM usercompany WHERE id = 1";
$resultVat = $connect->query($sqlvat);

if($resultVat->num_rows > 0) { 
 $row = $resultVat->fetch_array();
 $productVatValue=$row[0];
} // if num_rows

//$connect->close();

echo json_encode($productVatValue);  // original was $row, it gets the variable properly

//echo $productVatValue;
?>

[/code]
}